# How do I cross the lava in this room in Gerudo Ruins?

Tags: cadence-of-hyrule

I'm trying to make it through the Gerudo Ruins, and I'm pretty sure I need to cross this lava pit. The problem is, I don't have any idea how to do that.

[image: Lava pit room in Gerudo Ruins]

You can't hookshot the chest, since that puts you in the lava, and beyond that I'm completely stuck. What am I missing here?

Comment: You can blow up the chest with a bombchu and obtain the boss key and heart piece with the boomerang, but it still looks like I need to find a way across, unless those stairs don't lead to the boss door.

Comment: I haven't played the game, but I believe an item named the Goron Pendant will let you walk through lava without taking damage.

Comment: @Powerlord As lava is a deep liquid in CoH, you'd also need the Zora Flippers, but yes, that would work too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Push petrified Deadrocks into lava to create a path or get a Goron pendant.

---

There should be three [Deadrocks](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/Deadrock#Cadence_of_Hyrule) in that room. Deadrocks turn into stone when you hit them and are invulnerable for some time in almost all Zelda titles where they appear.

However, in Cadence of Hyrule, you can still push them around when they transformed into statues. If you push a petrified Deadrock into lava, they will melt down into hot stone and therefore create a path.

So in order to get the heart piece, you need to push two Deadrocks into the lava, and in order to get the treasure chest, you need to push one Deadrock into the lava.

Exiting and re-entering the room will make all of the Deadrocks respawn, in the event that you have killed them all with bombs.

Alternatively, get the Zora Flippers from the Zora prince and the Goron Pendant from the Goron shop, as the former enables you to swim and the latter further allows you to swim in lava.

Comment: You can also apparently use hover boots, which is what I ended up doing

Comment: @Unionhawk Yeah, hover boots are an universal cheat code in CoH :)